# How do I write a simple loop in a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to write a simple formula that concatenates each entry in a given column of a spreadsheet, interspersed with newline characters. In other words,

```
=CONCATENATE(B2, CHAR(10), B3, CHAR(10), B4, CHAR(10), ... , CHAR(10), B130)
```

Is there any way of achieve this without having to type the whole thing out by hand? Even copying and pasting so I just have to modify the cell references is pretty laborious. I was thinking that there might be some way of implementing a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `JOIN` function. This function *joins* all the elements in an array (ie. a 1-dimensional range, a single column or a single row) separated by a common delimiter (your `CHAR(10)`).

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10),B2:B130)
```

I believe the `CONCATENATE` function has a limit of 30 arguments, so that could also have been a problem.